# Scheduling one-time events with AT from PHP script not working

Tags: php, schedule

I need to use PHP to schedule tasks for later execution on a local machine. I am avoiding cron because I do not need to repeat the task over time.

I tried

```
$msg="at 10am today
date > /path/path/date.txt
\x04";
shell_exec($msg); // Nope

$msg="at 10am today
date > /path/path/date.txt
".chr(4);
shell_exec($msg); // Nope

$msg=<<<EOT
at 10am today
date > /path/path/date.txt
EOT;
shell_exec($msg); // Nope
```

and

```
shell_exec('echo "date > /some/path/date.txt" | at 10am today');
```

That last line works when executing the script with **php** in Terminal but not when going to the script in my web browser (`http://localhost/script.php`). I've tried `system` too but to no success. By the way, `echo shell_exec('ls /')` works without problem, so I don't think it's a permission issue? Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong?

---

**Background information**: the motivation for this is that I am building a web-based interface for specifying and submitting computationally intensive simulation jobs to remote machines. My PHP script generates R and Matlab scripts from user-input, and I can SSH into those machines from PHP just fine. I just can't schedule those scripts to be executed at a later time, independent of the SSH session.

Comment: if all you need is scheduling some tasks, crontab is enough http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probem is, as you suggest, on wich user execute the script. I think that the classic www-data can't use at command

Add dedicated user as normal user (adduser phpschedule);
Then change user that execute php in apache from classic www-data to phpschedule

Comment: Yes! Thank you! The user was the issue.

Mac OS X users: make user and change httpd.conf appropriately. Then add that user to `/var/at/at.allow`